# Distribution of SiteCollections

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, content-database, sharepoint-on-prem

I have the following scenario:

- 1 Content database
- 1 Webapplication with 28 Sitecollections

The Size of this content database is about 100 GB.

So I want to distribute newly created Sitecollections to the new content datbase.

Does sharepoint automatically distribute them?

Is it possible to move some sitecollection to the newly created content database?

Answer (score 1):

Powershell is the answer.

http://sharepointadam.com/2010/11/12/create-site-collection-in-new-content-database-script/

I use a script on our 2010 and 2013 solutions to create site collections and contentDBs in their own containers.

Answer (score 0):

their is no automatic way but you have to change the things little bit.
Here are steps:

- Create a new Content Database and set the additional permission(if any)
- Cap the existing Database to Max site collection 28 and warning level 27, Now no more site collection will be created in this DB.
- Now create the site collections and you will see it goes to new database.
  All above steps you can perform from Central Admin or you can do it via powershell.
  http://summit7systems.com/sharepoint-2010-and-2013-content-databases/

Moving Site collections.

Yes you can move site collections from one content DB to other. There is powershell command for this.

[Move-SpSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607915(v=office.15).aspx)